# Querying by a list of attributes, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, optimization, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to make queries that are filtered by membership in a list in SQLAlchemy? If so, would it generally be more efficient than my alternative?

This is how the code is currently structured. I believe that it may be inefficient due to the query being within two for loops.

```
def get_or_create(session, something):
    object = session.query(SomeModel).filter_by(attr=something).first()

    if object is None:
        object = make_new_object()

    return object

for things in stuff:
    objects = [get_or_create(session, something) for something in things]
```

I'm wondering if it would be possible to do something similar to the following, in order to reduce the total number of queries.

```
for things in stuff:   
    filter = if attr in things else None # pseudocode

    objects_or_none = session.query(SomeModel).filter_by(filter).all()

    objects = [make_new_object() if object is None
               else object
               for object in objects_or_none]
```

`objects_or_none` would look something like this `[object, object, None, object, None, object]`